# What's the omitted subject in sentence "I noticed that you like A and would like to recommend B for you"?

Tags: ellipsis, subjects

> I noticed that you like A and would like to recommend B for you.

What I'm trying to say is "I noticed that you like A, and I would like to recommend B for you".

But if I read the sentence like this:

> I • noticed that • you like A and would like to recommend B for you.

It becomes a little confusing to me, looks like the omitted subject could be "you". Am I doing anything wrong here?

Comment: "I noticed *something*." Why do you think "I" is not the subject of your sentence?

Answer (score 2):

The first sentence is correct, "**I**" would be the omitted subject.

In the joining of the ideas: 
"I noticed that you like A" with "**I** would like to recommend B *for you*."

The "*for you*" at the end is the main indicator that the speaker is the one recommending the book. If it ended with "for me" that would imply that "you" (the one who likes A) was the one recommending it.